# form to target div with file upload

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms, upload

I currently have a form in which the results are returned into a targeted div.
It works great. EXCEPT when my form includes an upload ( INPUT TYPE="FILE" NAME="PIC_UPLOAD" ), in which case it simply does not work. Any ideas on what I am missing?
Here is the current (working) code

```js
/* attach a submit handler to the form */
$("#testform").submit(function(event) {

  /* stop form from submitting normally */
  event.preventDefault();

  /* get some values from elements on the page: */
  var $form = $(this),
    url = $form.attr('action');

  /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
  $.post(url, $("#testform").serialize(),
    function(data) {
      var content = data;
      $('#targetdiv').empty().append(content);

    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="the form">

  <form action="destination_file.html" id="testform">

    <INPUT Type="hidden" NAME="func" VALUE="1004">
    <TEXTAREA NAME="NOTES" ROWS=4 COLS=34></TEXTAREA>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</div>
<hr>
<div id="targetdiv"> results to go here </div>
```

Comment: What does *formtest_rec.php* look like?

Comment: I don't think the code on the receiving end should matter regarding the ability of the form to POST data to it. In fact, that was just put here on this site as a place holder. I am not sure why the 'Run code snippet" does not function here, but you can see a lie example at http://www.oil-soft.com/v3/testing/formtest.mv    and with the file input field added here :  http://www.oil-soft.com/v3/testing/formtest_file.mv    It is apparent the file is not being included in the POST. I suspect something to do with .serialize

Comment: I think same origin policy prevents `$.post()` or `$.ajax()` from working in SO snippets.

Answer (score 0):

So, I was able to achieve POST'ing the form, with a file upload and target a div by switching to AJAX. See updated code:

```js
<script>


    /* attach a submit handler to the form */
    $("#testform").submit(function(event) {

      /* stop form from submitting normally */
      event.preventDefault();

      var form_data = new FormData($('testform')[0]);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'url_to_file_to_process_upload.php',
            data: form_data,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                $('#targetdiv').html(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert("Sorry, there was a problem!");
            },
            complete: function (xhr, status) {
                //$('#targetdiv').slideDown('slow')
            }
        });

    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you just use plain vanilla js instead of using jQuery...

Let HTML be the thing that describes how things should work and just make js a progressive enhancement. The site should work without js.
Often the best code is reusable code. so try writing your code a bit like

```js
async function ajaxify (evt) {
  evt.preventDefault()
  const form = evt.target
  const fd = new FormData(form)
  const res = await fetch(form.action, { method: form.method, body: fd })
  const text = await res.text()
}

$("form").submit(ajaxify)
```

No specific js logic is necessary, works for more forms. easy to update, change and manipulate from HTML, and the js/css file can be more static hosted on some CDN